# C# Внедрение DLL в ресурсы

Tags: c#, dll, htmlagilitypack

Похожие темы были, но немного другого формата. Как я могу добавив dll в ресурсы (в частности я использую HtmlAgilityPack.dll) использовать его потом так же, как я использовал бы, просто установив соответствующую NuGet сборку? Смысл в том, чтобы избавиться от необходимости хранения dll в папке с проектом.

Comment: При запуске такого приложения надо будет: 1) прочитать dll из ресурсов, 2)записать его в виде файла в ту же папку из которой было запущено приложение, 3) по окончании работы удалять этот файл. Только вот возникает резонный вопрос, а зачем нужны такие сложности? Ради чего? Вы возьмите для примера любое более-менее серьезное приложение и оно обязательно будет состоять не из одного десятка различных dll и проч. файлов, и что это как то отрицательно влияет на его работу?

Comment: Можно помещать dll в GAC. Это должен делать инсталлятор вашего приложения. Можно попробовать довольно широко известную утилиту ILMerge или альтернативы [тынц](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189549/5045688). Но это не всегда возможно.

Comment: Как вариант - взять исходники HtmlAgilityPack и внедрить в свой проект. Правда я не знаю что там по лицензированию будет если проект коммерческий.

Comment: Используйте ILMerge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
internal class LazyLoader
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
            var an = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            if (an.Name == "YourAssembly")
            {
                var resourcepath = "HtmlAgilityPack.dll";
                var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourcepath);
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    using (stream)
                    {
                      byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                      stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                      return Assembly.Load(data);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    LazyLoader.Setup();

    // ...
}
```